# Javascript function callback dependant on timeout

Tags: javascript, function, callback, timeout

I have a javascript function which makes a request to a web service and manipulates the response.

I would like to put a timeout within the function as the web service can be unstable at times.

In my example below I have two timeouts the second would be replaced by the request to the web service. However in the example below the callback is still run twice. Am I going about this the right way and how can I get the function to stop after the error callback is returned.

```
function fnWithTimeoutCallback(v1, v2, callback) {

    // set a timeout after 3 seconds

    setTimeout(function(){

        var err = true;

        var res = {};
        res.status = 'error';
        res.message = 'Request timed out.';

        return callback(err, res);

    }, 3000);

    // meanwhile do a bunch of stuff which makes requests to web services etc

    setTimeout(function(){

        var err = false;

        var res = {};
        res.status = 'success';
        res.message = 'Did stuff with web service.';

        return callback(err, res);

    }, 6000);

}


fnWithTimeoutCallback('v1', 'v2', function(err, res) {

    if(err) { 
        console.log('There was an error: ' + res.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Worked!' + res.message);
    }

});
```

Comment: What library are you using to make web service calls ? The library you are using might already have a timeout setting which you can use instead of you trying to do it explicitly.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a legacy bit of code making the call which I wanted to avoid touching if possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use clearTimeout function to clear the timeouts, you will need to save the setTimeout to a variable and clear as required.

```
var timeout1 = setTimeout (function(){
//check and clear timeout2
  clearTimeout(timeout2);
},6000);

var timeout2 = setTimeout (function(){
//check and clear timeout1
clearTimeout(timeout1);
},6000);
```